# Query Firebase Documents with unknown document name in the middle

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My Firebase Setup is basically like this:

**Collection Users** (documents with field: userID) -> **Collection wishlists** (documents with field: name) -> **Collection wünsche**

What I would like is query for `wünsche` but for that I would like to use this code, which is not allowed:

```
db
  .collection("users")
  .document(userID)
  .collection("wishlists")
  .document.whereField("name", isEqualTo: list.name) // <- this is the crucial part which I would like to call but is not possible
  .collection("wünsche")
  .order(by: "wishCounter")
  .getDocuments() {( querySnapshot, error) in }
```

Is there any workaround for this so I can use `.collection` after a `whereField()` ?

Comment: Hey Chris, if what Bradley mentioned is not solving your question it might be owrht updating your questions and/or code to mach the current issue so we can have a better understading of the issue.

Comment: @Edgardo it didnt really solve the issue as I couldnt figure out what exactly I should call in my case... looked at the doc and watched some tutorials but still stuck...

Answer (score 0):

Basically: you can't do this, it's not how Firestore Queries work. You can query from a single collection at a time (with the exception of Collection Group Queries).

When you use `whereField` you're forming a Firestore `Query` object where you will retrieve a list of Documents in the original Collection.

So this is alone valid Firestore `Query` object, which you can then call `get()` on:

```swift
db.collection("users").document(userID)
.collection("wishlists").document.whereField("name", isEqualTo: list.name)
```

You **cannot** then query Sub-Collections inside that original query, unless you are querying a sub-collection for a *specific Document* or are performing a [Collection Group Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query). (It sounds like Collection Group Queries will best fit your use-case, so give the documentation a look).

Comment: I am struggling with the syntax.. I can not call `collectionGroup` on a `document` or a `collection`?

Comment: You call `collectionGroup` just at the root of the database, and it automatically queries across all collections/subcollections that match that name, no matter how deeply they are nested. Therefore, it's important that the names of the sub-collections you want to search across all have the same name, and that name isn't used elsewhere in the database.

Comment: Check the link in the answer, it gives some examples. Note that you can't filter based on data in the parent document/collection, so you might need to put some data (like `"name"` from `wishlists` into `wünsche` and filter from there.

Comment: I looked at the examples, but in my case I have `users`  for example as a Parent Collection. How do I ensure that I only search for the current users `wishlists`  ?? Im quite confused here